# Разворачивание значений в словаре по ключу через функцию

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь вида `d = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': ['eggs', 'test']}`.
Необходимо с использованием функции (не lambda) осуществить смену местами ключа и значения(ий) таким образом, чтобы из исходных данным получилось такая картина:

```py
d = {'bar':'foo', 'eggs': 'spam', 'test': 'spam'}
```

Как сделать "разворот" ключа с одним значением мне понятно:

```py
def f(k):
    d[d.pop(k)] = k
    print(d)
f('foo')
```

Вполне ожидаемо получаем:

```py
{'spam': ['eggs', 'test'], 'bar': 'foo'}
```

Но вот с несолькими значениями у одного ключа уже возникают проблемы и на вызов функции:
`f('spam')` мы получаем ошибку:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в лоб, то можно проверять тип данных, который лежит под ключом и если это список, то прогонять по всем значениям данного списка. Как то так:

```py
d = {'foo': 'bar', 'spam': ['eggs', 'test']}

def f(inn:dict) -> dict:
    result = {}
    for key, value in inn.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                result[item] = key
        else:
            result[value] = key
    return result

f(d)

# out
# {'bar': 'foo', 'eggs': 'spam', 'test': 'spam'}
```

И я все-таки сторонник не использовать внешние переменные в функции, а передавать данные через параметры и возвращать результат. Снимает ответственность с функции за внешними изменения и в дальнейшем ее можно использовать как черный ящик, без привязки к внешним изменениям